# C++ function pointer argument with template

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, language-lawyer, function-pointers

I'm trying to use a function pointer with template as an argument. But the compiler seems to have trouble handling lambda and nullptr.

Everything is fine when I change `void (*callback)(T input)` to `void (*callback)(int input)` in the following code.

Is this compiler behavior specified by the C++ standard?

The compile command I use is `$ g++ main.cpp -std=c+11` but the same behavior found in Visual Studio 2019.

```cpp
template <class T>
int dummy (T tmp, void (*callback)(T input)) {
    // Doesn't do anything, just trying to compile
    // If I change (T input) to (int input), it compiles fine  
    if (callback)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

void callback (int input) {
    return;
}

int main () {
    int tmp = 10;
    auto callback_lambda = [](int input) -> void {
        return;
    };

    dummy(tmp, callback); // Compiles OK
    dummy(tmp, callback_lambda); // Error: mismatched types 'void (*)(T)' and 'main()::<lambda(<int>)'
    dummy(tmp, nullptr); // Error: no matching function for call to 'dummy(int&, std:nullptr_t)'
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that implicit conversion won't be considered in [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions).

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution), which happens later.

So when passing lambda and `nullptr`, the conversions to the function pointer aren't considered, the template parameter `T` can't be deduced for the 2nd function argument and then cause the error.

You can make the 2nd function parameter to [non-deduced context](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts), to exclude it from deduction, with the help of [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity).

> `type_identity` can be used to block [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction):

e.g.

```
template <class T>
int dummy (T tmp, void (*callback)(std::type_identity_t<T>)) {
    ...
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GKnhZZaCb7LGualX)

PS: If your compiler doesn't support [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) (since C++20), you can define your own version, it's not difficult.

Comment: This explains well. Looking at `std::type_identity`, I have impressions that C++ getting just complicated though. Anyway thank you for your answer!

Comment: I find `std::type_identity_t<void(*)(T)> callback` more readable than `void (*callback)(std::type_identity_t<T>)`